# python - insert node to a specfic place in doubly linked list

Tags: python, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to figure out how to insert a node into a specific place in a doubly linked list. Ive looked at other problems similar to this on here but they all seem slightly different, I'm also fairly new to python so I don't understand some of the code that is in those problems and solutions

Im trying to loop through the list starting at the head with a counter of 0 that increases 1 with each node and when the counter is equal to the position where you want to insert it, set the previous node to the new node

I want it to output - a, b, c - with b being what was inserted and it just outputs - a, c -

```py
class DoublyLinkedList:
  def __init__(self):
    self.head_node = None
    self.tail_node = None
  
  def insert(self, pos, new_value):
    new_node = Node(new_value)
    if pos == 0:
      self.add_to_head(new_node)
    else:
      current_node = self.head_node
      for i in range(pos):
        if current_node.get_next_node() is None:
          self.add_to_tail(new_node)
          return
      current_node = current_node.get_next_node()

    counter = 0
    current_node = self.head_node
    while counter != pos:
      current_node = current_node.get_next_node()
      counter += 1 
    if counter == pos:
      current_node.set_prev_node(new_node)
      
      

  def add_to_head(self, new_value):
    new_head = Node(new_value)
    current_head = self.head_node

    if current_head != None:
      current_head.set_prev_node(new_head)
      new_head.set_next_node(current_head)

    self.head_node = new_head

    if self.tail_node == None:
      self.tail_node = new_head

  def add_to_tail(self, new_value):
    new_tail = Node(new_value)
    current_tail = self.tail_node

    if current_tail != None:
      current_tail.set_next_node(new_tail)
      new_tail.set_prev_node(current_tail)

    self.tail_node = new_tail

    if self.head_node == None:
      self.head_node = new_tail

  def print(self):
    current_node = self.head_node
    while current_node is not None:
      print(f"{current_node.get_value()}", end=" ")
      current_node = current_node.get_next_node()
    print()

class Node:
  def __init__(self, value, next_node=None, prev_node=None):
    self.value = value
    self.next_node = next_node
    self.prev_node = prev_node
    
  def set_next_node(self, next_node):
    self.next_node = next_node
    
  def get_next_node(self):
    return self.next_node

  def set_prev_node(self, prev_node):
    self.prev_node = prev_node
    
  def get_prev_node(self):
    return self.prev_node
  
  def get_value(self):
    return self.value
  
dll = DoublyLinkedList()
dll.add_to_head('a')
dll.add_to_tail('c')
dll.print()
dll.insert(1, 'b')
dll.print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- Your `insert` function foresees to insert the new node at the start (using `add_to_head`) or at the end (using `add_to_tail`), but those methods expect the *value* as argument, not a node instance. You'll see that when you pass 0 for `pos`, the result is not right either.
- For other cases there is only one statement that modifies a link in the linked list: `current_node.set_prev_node(new_node)` Yet, to insert a node between two others, you'll need to set **four** references, so this one statement cannot be enough.
- There is an indentation issue.

  1. In the first loop: `current_node = current_node.get_next_node()` should be executed in each iteration of the loop, but the statement is positioned *outside* of the loop.
  2. The second part of the `insert` code should stay within the main `else` block -- so it doesn't execute when the first `if` condition was true.
- Not a problem, but the `if counter == pos` statement right after the second loop will always have a true condition, since the loop condition was the negation of it.

Here is a fix of your `insert` function:

```
  def insert(self, pos, new_value):
    # Don't create node yet
    if pos == 0:
      self.add_to_head(new_value)  # Pass value
    else:
      current_node = self.head_node
      for i in range(pos):
        if current_node.get_next_node() is None:
          self.add_to_tail(new_value)  # Pass value
          return
        current_node = current_node.get_next_node()  # Fixed indentation

      counter = 0
      current_node = self.head_node
      while counter != pos:
        current_node = current_node.get_next_node()
        counter += 1
      # Perform 4 updates to references in the linked list (unconditional)
      #    Use the optional arguments of the Node constructor to perform 2 of them
      new_node = Node(new_value, current_node, current_node.get_prev_node())
      new_node.get_prev_node().set_next_node(new_node)
      current_node.set_prev_node(new_node)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this example

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Node:
    value: str
    nextNode: 'Node' = None
    prevNode: 'Node' = None

    def add(self, n: 'Node', pos: int = 0):
        if pos == 0:
            if self.nextNode:
                n.nextNode = self.nextNode
                self.nextNode = n
            else:
                self.nextNode = n
            return
        if not self.nextNode:
            self.nextNode = n
            return
        self.nextNode.add(n, pos-1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = Node('1')
    n2 = Node('2')
    n3 = Node('3')
    n.add(n2)
    n.add(n3, 2)
    print(n)
```